# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. If $f\in C^1$ then is true that if $Df(a) = 0$ for some $a$ then $Df(x) = 0$ in a neighborhood of $a$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. If $f\in C^1$ then is true that if $Df(a) = 0$ for some $a$ then $Df(x) = 0$ in a neighborhood of $a$?

It is strange, for example, $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}.$ We have that $f'(0) = 0$ but it is the unique point such that the claim holds. So it is false?

Comment: The claim is false. Another counterexample is $f(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's false as others have noted. I think that there's a more closely related claim, namely that if

$$
Df(a) \ne 0
$$
and $f$ is $C^1$, then 
$$
Df(x) \ne 0
$$
for all $x$ in some neighborhood of $a$, i.e., I've switched inequality for equality.

This fact is useful in the proofs of the inverse and implicit function theorems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the claim is false, and your example disproves the claim.  Another, somewhat simpler, counterexample is
$$
f(x) = {1 \over 2} x^2.
$$

The closest-sounding claim to yours that is true (and that I know of) is the statement that if an analytic function of a complex variable is zero in a neighborhood of a point in its connected domain, then the function is identically zero in that domain.  (See Cartan's "Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions.")